# BigQuery STRUCT Syntax

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Given following struct structure. In below leaf node is `field1`, `field2` the rest are object structure containing the leaf.

```
dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field1
dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field2
dimension1.dimension2.field1
dimension2.dimension2.field2
dimension1.field1
```

Q1. How do I rename field2 from both `dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field2` and `dimension2.dimension2.field2` while maintaining rest of the structure? I found example to replace one level of nested struct but unable to do this for nested struct.

Q2. The leaf name `field1` appears in different struct locations. When I attempt to perform select statement such as below I am getting error messages saying duplicate name is not supported. I'm not sure how is below duplicate as paths for all fields are different. How can I get around this issue?

```
     SELECT dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field1
     dimension1.dimension2.field1
     dimension1.field1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below examples are for BigQuery Standard SQL

> How do I rename field2 from both dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field2 and dimension2.dimension2.field2 while maintaining rest of the structure?

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT 
  STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension2 STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension3 STRUCT<field1 INT64, field3 INT64>>>
    (dimension1.field1, STRUCT(dimension1.dimension2.field1, STRUCT(dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field1, dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field2))
  ) dimension1,
  STRUCT<dimension2 STRUCT<field4 INT64>>(STRUCT(dimension2.dimension2.field2)) dimension2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 
    STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension2 STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension3 STRUCT<field1 INT64, field2 INT64>>>(1, STRUCT(11, STRUCT(21, 22))) dimension1,
    STRUCT<dimension2 STRUCT<field2 INT64>>(STRUCT(31)) dimension2
)
SELECT 
  STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension2 STRUCT<field1 INT64, dimension3 STRUCT<field1 INT64, field3 INT64>>>
    (dimension1.field1, STRUCT(dimension1.dimension2.field1, STRUCT(dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field1, dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field2))
  ) dimension1,
  STRUCT<dimension2 STRUCT<field4 INT64>>(STRUCT(dimension2.dimension2.field2)) dimension2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> I am getting error messages saying duplicate name is not supported. ... How can I get around this issue?

Just use aliases as in below  example

```
SELECT 
  dimension1.dimension2.dimension3.field1 AS a,
  dimension1.dimension2.field1 AS b,
  dimension1.field1 AS c
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```